# Is there a way to list all 4G networks within range?

Tags: mobile-data, data-connection, 4g

Does anyone know of a method to obtain a list of all 4G networks within range at the current location?

Currently running Android 7.1 on an HTC U11 if relevant.

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.staircase3.opensignal